# Attributed String Foreground color not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

I am using the following code to change the `foreground color` and `font` of a attribute string using `Swift`. But the Font changing perfectly without any problem but the `foreground color` is not changing

```
var checklistText = NSMutableAttributedString()
        checklistText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(lblChecklistName.text!),\(checklistName)")
        checklistText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                                   value: UIFont(
                                    name: "Helvetica",
                                    size: 11.0)!,
                                   range: NSRange(location: lblChecklistName.text!.length(), length: checklistName.length()))
        checklistText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location: lblChecklistName.text!.length(), length: checklistName.length()+1))
        lblChecklistName.attributedText = checklistText
```

Comment: i think String doesn't not method `length`, i use `.characters.count`

Comment: There is some problem with range you are passing.

Comment: When using correct ranges your code works ok. Check the ranges you're using.

Answer (score 11):

I have meet the same issue. Although I'm not using ranges to construct a `AttributedString` 
My code looked like

```swift
self.contentTextLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "content",
                                                            attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, .background: UIColor.blue])
```

When running, the background color shows blue, but the foreground color does not appear red. I thought it a swift's issue, so I also tried it in Objective-C, but still does not work.

I'm using storyboard and I resolved this by remove the named color set on that label. I think it's Apple's bug, somehow named color set on label have override foreground color set in attributed string.

Comment: `I'm using storyboard and I resolved this by remove the named color set on that label. I think it's Apple's bug, somehow named color set on label have override foreground color set in attributed string.`
Yes, this is apple bug, and still is an issue for Xcode ver 11.3.1. Setting the color from the code is fine, but setting `named color` from the storyboard breaks the foreground color in attributedText. Note that setting system color from the storyboard works fine (the bug appears for custom asset catalog colors).

Answer (score 11):

For `foregroundColor` to work you need to set the `.strokeWidth` to negative :

```
let attributes : [ NSAttributedString.Key : Any ] = [.font : UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 11.0),
                                                             .foregroundColor : UIColor.red,
                                                             .strokeWidth : -5]
        let stringWithAttributes = NSAttributedString(string: "YOUR STRING", attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: Wow! works like a charm. Any explanation on why -ve value works with foreground color?

Answer (score 3):

Set strokeWidth to negative and strokeColor as desired color.
This worked for me. It works with namedColor.

```
let gdprString = "test test test"

let gdprAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: 
    NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0),
    NSAttributedString.Key.link: gdprString,
    NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: -3.0,      
    NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: UIColor.blue 
] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check your label text color. If you setup your label text color after giving attributed text value, it may overrides attributed color.

```
yourLabel.attributedText = attrStr //attributed string
yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 1):

On my case, its happened on ios below 13. Add negative strokeWidth will do the trick.

```
NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: -3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

April 2021, I have the same bug and nothing from the above helped me. But this helped:

Set `textColor` of the label to any color before you set an `attributedText`.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.textColor = .black

label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, World!", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I just wasted a bunch of time on this same issue with the new `AttributedString`.  Named colors do not work for `AttributedString` foreground color.

This does not work:

```
attributedString.foregroundColor = .blue
```

This works:

```
attributedString.foregroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Avoid using named colors with text color (foregroundColor) for AttributedString.

Comment: I think it does work in macOS but doesn't on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Reference form: [**NSMutableAttributedString**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-set-use-multiple-font-colors-in.html)

```
var myString:NSString = "I AM KIRIT MODI"
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as 
String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
            myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:2,length:2))
lbl_First.attributedText = myMutableString
```

**See Image :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried that but thats not working

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same issue. Although I'm not using ranges to construct a AttributedString.
So I found a weird thing that you should set the textcolor for label or textfield to clear and then set the colors through attributed string. Here is a sample code:

```
//Have to set the textColor to clear to make attributed string of multiple foreground colors
    termsAndConditionsLabel.textColor = .clear
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "By signing up, you agree to our", attributes: [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(resource: .captionRegular),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: ThemeManager.shared.gray1
    ])
    let optionString = NSAttributedString(string: " Terms and Conditions", attributes: [
                                            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(resource: .captionRegular),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: ThemeManager.shared.systemBlue
    ])
    
    attributedString.append(optionString)
    
    termsAndConditionsLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

for UIButton this issue solves by:

```
let bin = UIButton(type: .system)
btn.setTitleColor(nil, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Was using iOS 16 simulator. My issue was that I was setting a `.link` value (even if it was an empty string) which made the text color always blue. Checking for `nil` or `""` before setting the link attributed property helped